# Filtered routes in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am building Angular 2 application and having a little conceptual problem.

In my application, I have a dashboard page which contains search-bar, navigation list and a router-outlet for the content to show.
In my navigation list I have several links which include :

- All Items,
- My items,
- Pending Items...

When I click on each of the links I am getting navigated to  /items  which is handled by ItemsModule and ItemsComponent.
I have already implemented the routes and the links but I am struggling with the idea of how to determine which link I've used.

I thought about several ways to implement it :

1. Route with parameters and then use switch-case inside the component to see what "filter" did I use (All / My / Pending).
2. Specific route options - for example I'll add 3 routes : 
   2.1   /items                -  to show all items
   2.2   /items/my          -  to show my items
   2.3   /items/pending  -  to show pending items

In addition, as I mentioned above, I have a search-bar to search for a specific item (whether I am at 'All' / 'My' / 'Pending' items).
I wonder how can I combine all of the navigations and routing and get it all work together.

Let me know if someone has figured a way to "solve" my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 3 paths:

```
{path: 'items', component: ItemsComponent},
{path: 'items/:type', component: ItemsComponent},
{path: 'items/:type/:searchString', component: ItemsComponent}
```

In the component:

```
this._route.params.subscribe(p => {
  var searchString = p["searchString"];
    switch(p["type"]) {
      case 'all':
         //do something
         break;
      case 'mine':
         //do something
         break;
      case 'pending':
         //do something
         break;
      default:
         //do something
         break;
    }
}
```